# Retrieve token list from ParserRuleContext

Tags: antlr, antlr4

### Main question

Is there an easy way to get a list of tokens (ideally in a form of a `TokenStream`) from the parser rule class `ParserRuleContext`?

#### Related answers

In an answer for a question [Traversal of tokens using ParserRuleContext in listener - ANTLR4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941553/traversal-of-tokens-using-parserrulecontext-in-listener-antlr4/29954429#comment68291767_29954429) this solution appeared:

```java
ParserRuleContext pctx = ctx.getParent();
List<TerminalNode> nodes = pctx.getTokens(pctx.getStart(), pctx.getStop());
```

But there is no method with signature `ParserRuleContext::getTokens(Token, Token)` in ANTLRv4.

#### My solution

I thought about retriving a list of tokens from `TokenStream` by using `TokenStream:get(index: int)` method, where `index` value will be set to a range of indicies of given `ParserRuleContext` start/stop tokens.

### Additional question

Is there a way to get a subset of tokens from `TokenStream` in a form of another `TokenStream`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I overlooked some classes and their inferfaces in the ANTLRv4 API.

### Answer to main question

Proposed above solution is correct. Also `BufferedTokenStream` and `CommonTokenStream` classes have method `public List<Token> getTokens(int start, int stop)` which allows to retrive list of tokens from a given range (especially from a range between start token and stop token of `ParserRuleContext` class)

### Answer to additional question

You can utilize `ListTokenSource` class which implements `TokenSource` interface. Then you can create `CommonTokenStream` class passing the `ListTokenSource`.

### Code example of ParserRuleRewriter

I encapsulate above ideas into small code example featuring `ParserRuleRewriter` - a `TokenStreamRewriter` that rewrites only given parser rule. In the code `tokenStream` parameter is a token stream of a full program.

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import java.util.List;

public class ParserRuleRewriter {
    private TokenStreamRewriter rewriter;

    public ParserRuleRewriter(ParserRuleContext parserRule, CommonTokenStream tokenStream) {
        Token start = parserRule.getStart();
        Token stop = parserRule.getStop();
        List<Token> ruleTokens = tokenStream.getTokens(start.getTokenIndex(), stop.getTokenIndex());
        ListTokenSource tokenSource = new ListTokenSource(ruleTokens);
        CommonTokenStream commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(tokenSource);
        commonTokenStream.fill();
        rewriter = new TokenStreamRewriter(commonTokenStream);
    }

    public void replace(Token token, ParserRuleContext rule) {
        rewriter.replace(token, rule.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return rewriter.getText();
    }
}
```